# LibGDX cross platform websocket solution (Android,iOS,Desktop,HTML5)

Tags: websocket, libgdx, cross-platform

I am developing a cross platform game using LibGDX.
I was searching for a websockets implementation for LibGDX that works on Android,iOS,Desktop and HTML5 platforms. Unfortunately I did not find anything relevant.I still hardly believe that such a trivial thing is not a part of the framework. Am I missing something ?

Does it means I should create an abstract class or interface and connect concrete implementation for each backend ? Sounds like a lot of work...

Anyone can suggest any ready to use solution ?
One that works against [Echo Test](https://www.websocket.org/echo.html) is good enough for me.

Comment: As far as i know there is no solution yet. You need to write native interfaces and implementations yourself.

Comment: Ohh snap :( Now need to understand how to make extensions using roboVM...

Comment: Take a look into the wiki: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Networking as far as i see thould ios work but not gwt but i dont have any own experience with this.

Comment: @BennX - Been there , it is about plain old sockets not the websockets. It is actually very different things.